# HTML scripts for sending email

Tags: html

I'm completely new. the first thing I wanna do is to put a field and a button in my website. I want it to work like this: user writes his/her email address in the field and pushes the send button. I should receive an email with user's email address as the body of the message. sorry if my question is too easy. Appreciate your help. Elham

Comment: You can't do this with HTML only. However you can look for the `mailto` URI scheme, it may perhaps suit you. Example: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible with HTML alone.

Comment: so what can I do? appreciate if you could help

Comment: You could install PHP on your server. Most likely your server already has PHP. If not, you should change your server provider.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plain HTML. There are two possibilities:

- Use mailto links, for example `<a href="mailto:john.doe@example.org">Leave Feedback</a>`. Clicking this will open the default mail client of the user. You can also predefine subject and other fields.

  Drawback is that lots of users are not using a real mail client any more and rely on web services instead. They will most likely not be able to use that link.
- Rely on server-side software (as backend) that send the mail. You will either need support for server side scripts like PHP, Perl or others; and some form mailer software that handles this for you. In your HTML page, embed a form that send the data to the backend software.

  You might also want to rely on some web service capable of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only thing you want to do use a service that handles this for you, http://htmlcontactbox.com/ for instance. But if you want to do this yourself (or you want to learn at all) you need some server side language, like PHP, etc.